# Google Chrome not installing on Ubuntu 16.04.03

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome

After downloading package when I click to install it, it's showing

> waiting to install

on unity panel. Log files are-

```
Sep 16 08:53:02 kk-Ubuntu gnome-session[1440]: (gnome-software:1592): Gs-WARNING **: failed to call gs_plugin_app_install on apt: 
GDBus.Error:org.debian.apt.TransactionFailed: error-no-package:
Package google-chrome-stable isn't available

Sep 16 08:53:02 kk-Ubuntu gnome-session[1440]: (gnome-software:1592): Gs-WARNING **: not saving error for (null):
GDBus.Error:org.debian.apt.TransactionFailed: error-no-package:
Package google-chrome-stable isn't available
```

Comment: Please try `sudo apt install /path/to/your/package.deb` and [add](https://askubuntu.com/posts/956284/edit) the output to your question in a code block (`{}` button) if it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: thanks all, I installed Gdebi package installer, and everything runs fine after that.

Comment: In order to avoid future problems please understand that the Ubuntu Software needs APT to run and make a list of installed and available software updates. So, before installing any new software, always fully update your system (as easy as running the Updates tool).

Answer (score 0):

I installed Gdebi package installer, with the command `sudo apt-get install gdebi` and thene installed the google package as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/170557/225694) and everything runs fine after that.

Note: you have to enable the universe repository first to install `gdebi` as described [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: I can only assume that you used `gdebi` to install a previously downloaded deb package. Perhaps you would be so kind as to add detail as explained in [the guidelines](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) so that others can benefit from your experience.

Comment: After downloading Google chrome .deb file I downloaded gdebi package installer from ubuntu software store. Then installed it. After that I select chrome installer, right click on it and opened it with gdebi installer. That's all. Its very easy. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add information instead of posting a comment.